# Godaddy Emails Stop Working after Connecting to Shopify

Tags: email, shopify, mx-record

After I connected my domain to shopify, the emails I have on Godaddy hosting (not the workspace webmail) stop working
The current DNS records are as follow:

A (Host):

```
@ ==> shopify ip
```

CName:

```
www ==> example.myshopify.com
imap ==> imap.secureserver.net
pop ==> pop.secureserver.net
smtp ==> smtp.secureserver.net
```

MX:

```
@ ==> smtp.example.com
```

I tried different MX records but none seem to work, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It's best to contact GoDaddy support on this matter. In most cases is not a very good idea to change the MX records.

Comment: @drip did that but all they did was change the mx record to mail.example.com which is pointing to nowhere (and they just told me to wait 48 hours for the change to propagate) - of course that didn't work

Comment: your mx must point to godaddy mail server

Comment: @JCharette you are right, I added A record 'mail.example.com' ==> ip address found in cpanel and that seems to solve the problem

now stupid godaddy is restricting my domain to 1 email per hour possibly due to all the testing I did, but that's a separate issue

Thanks!